# botnets Domain names List

Tags: botnet

how I can obtain the latest list of the latest revealed botnets domain list

I am looking for the DGA-based botnet in particular

I want to collect 1000,000 generated domain list to seed them to my research algorithm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

collecting that much of domain names you need to dig internet like anything
try this link, might help you. definitely not going to get that much of names give it a try
http://www.malwaredomains.com/?tag=botnets

All the best